# Are the properties of a model not used in a view still passed to client?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm taking too much time to create my views, and I have too much small views so I'm looking for a shortcut. I basically have 3 layers : DAL - Business - Presentation. I am thinking about directly using my business objects as view models. I would like to do it for the views which doesn't contain any form and which are only for displaying an entity. Because I feel like I'm really wasting time.

I'll be only using certain fields of these domain entiies in my views therefore I have a security question. I'm wondering if the properties that I don't use in my razor file are still sent to the client in the HTTP response even if I don't use them.

Thank you for your help

Comment: They are not, however a few things you need to consider.  One, if someone discovers a property in your domain entity and injects that into the POST, it is possible for a value to be overwritten that you were not expecting.  More importantly, what will you do in instances where you need multiple properties from multiple domain entities?  It may seem like a little more work, but by using View Models instead of domain models, you will make life easier going forward by each object in your code having a specific purpose.

Comment: Thanks @Tommy I didn't intended to do it with forms so there is no risk regarding injection. Concerning the multiple entities,  theorically I can still manage using partial views. However I understand the consequences you mentionned regarding the quality of the resulting code. I'll think about it.

Comment: No problem.  It is one of those things, if you are building a simple app, then go with the easy/straightforward route.  But, if you are starting a project that has the potential to grow large, then it is always easier to start the right way than having to go back and refactor in the future.  PS - don't know about the downvote, it wasn't me :)

Comment: Thank you, you perfectly answered my question. I'm going to continue with the ViewModel since it's a new project which is likely to evolve in the future. I'm near the end of that project and I began to lose my patience. What you're saying makes perfect sense.

Comment: I went ahead and made this an answer since my comment conversation answered your questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not, however a few things you need to consider.

1. If someone discovers a property in your domain entity and injects that into the POST, it is possible for a value to be overwritten that you were not expecting.
2. More importantly, what will you do in instances where you need multiple properties from multiple domain entities? It may seem like a little more work, but by using View Models instead of domain models, you will make life easier going forward by each object in your code having a specific purpose.

It is one of those things, if you are building a simple app, then go with the easy/straightforward route of using the domain models. But, if you are starting a project that has the potential to grow large, then it is always easier to start the right way than having to go back and refactor in the future.